# mongodb: flatten/ merge object with arrays to single array for all documents in collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have the following document structure in my collection:

**ISSUE:**

```
{
  "fruits": {
    "brasil": [
      "pineapple",
      "mango",
    ],
    "france": [
      "apple",
      "grape"
    ],
  },
}
```

**GOAL:**

```
{
  "fruits": [
    "brasil_pineapple",
    "brasil_mango",
    "france_apple",
    "france_grape"
  ]
}
```

For easier processing, i want to reduce the value of fruits to a single list containing all lists from the values of the keys in the object "fruits" and prefix each list item with the respective key to maintain uniqueness.

How can i convert all documents to the desired document structure?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You might consider another data model, something like `{"countryFruits": [{"country": "brasil", "fruits": ["pineapple", "mango"]}, {"country": "france", "fruits": ["apple", "grape"]}]}`. Or maybe even a different document for each country, `{"country": "brasil", "fruits": ["pineapple", "mango"]}, {"country": "france", "fruits": ["apple", "grape"]}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @rickhg12hs mentioned in the comment, you may want to consider another schema for easier processing. Nevertheless, for your currently proposed schema, you can use `$objectToArray` to convert `fruits` into array of k-v tuples and use `$reduce` and `$map` to iterate the arrays.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "fruits": {
        "$objectToArray": "$fruits"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      fruits: {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$fruits",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$concatArrays": [
              "$$value",
              {
                "$map": {
                  "input": "$$this.v",
                  "as": "f",
                  "in": {
                    $concat: [
                      "$$this.k",
                      "_",
                      "$$f"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/C5uIy6YAzqK)